# How to customize the cursor using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I Need to customize my Cursor inside a Website.

When the user **presses the <kbd><</kbd> Key**, the Cursor should Change to a specific Cursor.

I tried to add a **GIF** and alternatively an **SVG** to the Cursor, by adding a class on key-press Event
and a corresponding **CSS**:

```
.xlock {
/*cursor: n-resize;*/
cursor: url('../cursors/x-lock.svg'), auto;
}
```

The implemented n-resize-Cursor works perfect but I could not get the svg to work. So the **CSS**and the class obviously work.
The **SVG** is located in the Content/cursors Folder and the css-file is located in Content/SchemeEditor, so the link also should work.
**My last try was to call the Cursor for the Body:**

```
body {
height: 100vh;
cursor: url('../cursors/x-lock.svg'), auto;
}
```

I have no idea what's wrong here…

**This is the SVG:**

```
<svg width="150" height="60" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g>
  <line y2="30" x2="0" y1="0" x1="50" stroke-width="1" stroke="#000000" fill="none" opacity="1"/>
  <line y2="60" x2="50" y1="30" x1="0" stroke-width="1" stroke="#000000" fill="none" opacity="1"/>
  <line y2="30" x2="150" y1="0" x1="100" stroke-width="1" stroke="#000000" fill="none" opacity="0.2"/>
  <line y2="30" x2="150" y1="60" x1="100" stroke-width="1" stroke="#000000" fill="none" opacity="0.2"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Then he'll have to demo it.

Comment: ...hmmm first comment missing? WHAT do I have to demo?

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to use `.ico` file instead of `.svg`.

change your svg to ico

```
cursor: url('https://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-custom-cursor.ico'),auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

So guys,
as I said above, I tried svg and gif and at least I tried png-files.
Now I created some cur-files and it works with them.
No idea, why other filetypes doesn't but as it works this way, that's it.

Thanks for your suggestions.